# grep is not working as expected

Tags: linux

i have tried to grep in a file ......
in file i have 5 entities

```
vivek
vivek.a
a.vivek
vivek_a
a_vivek
```

when i grep as `grep -iw vivek` filename, then it should give me 
vivek only but it give

```
vivek
vivek.a
a.vivek
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of characters with letters, underscore and digits is considered as a word. So any other character apart from that set denotes the word boundary. Therefore, in the line "vivek.a", the dot denotes end of word, and all the characters before that form a word "vivek", which matches with the word you are trying to match using option -w.

So, one way is to define your own word boundaries like this:

```
$ grep -i -e "[[:space:]]vivek[[:space:]]" -e "^vivek[[:space:]]" -e "[[:space:]]vivek$" -e "^vivek$" file
```

Comment: hi sahaj this command is working fine for  vivek, vivek_a,a_vivek but for vivek.a and a.vivek, it give both . and _ value . I just replaced the vivek as vivek.a vivek_a   for that

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me. `.` is a non-word character. If you meant something else then you should have used a more-specific regex instead of using `-w`.

Comment: so there is no option,by which i can diff b/w vivek nd vivek.a

Comment: Nope. If you want to have an anchored regex then anchor your regex.

Answer (score 2):

It does that because the definition of a *word* (which is what the `w` option chooses) permits `.` to separate words, though `_` is considered part of a word.  This definition is useful for programming languages, but not so useful for English text.

Comment: Actually, `_` *is* considered a word character.

Comment: but here it's woeking fine for _ option ,only problem is .